# Using complex derivative to shows that a function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

If we know $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \equiv  f'(z)=0$ where $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ why do we need to check the Cauchy Riemann equations are all equal to zero, before concluding that $f$ is constant? (The solution to a question I am doing requires this extra step). Can't we just conclude it from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =  f'(z)=0$

Comment: How do you prove that $f'=\mathbf 0\implies f\text{ is constant}$?

Comment: Fair point. I suppose the easiest way is with Cauchy Riemann.

Comment: For example, $f(z) = \bar z$ has zero $\partial /\partial z$ - derivative (understood as $\frac12 (u_x-iv_y)$) but is nonconstant.

Comment: Note that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are equivalent to $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$. So requiring the Cauchy-Riemann equations amounts to forbidding any variation of @900sit-upsaday's example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know that the function $f$ is holomorphic, the assertion  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \equiv  f'(z)$ does not even make sense, since $f'$ needn't exist.
Anyway, if $g$ is any non constant holomorphic function on some domain $D$, its conjugate $f=\bar g$ satisfies  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =0$ but is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of the relevant theorem is: if $f$ is holomorphic on a domain $D$ and $f^\prime=0$ on $D$, then $f$ is constant in $D$.

The idea of the proof is to show (1) that $f$ is constant in a disk contained in $D$ and (2) use the fact that $D$ is connected to extend this fact to the entire domain.

To show the first fact, since $f$ is holomorphic, we have $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$ in the disk (from the Cauchy-Riemann equations). Then, we can use the corresponding theorem for functions mapping $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ on the real and imaginary components (i.e. $u$ and $v$) to show that $f$ must be constant.